# Py.test results reporting to Jira, Adaptavist

Tags: python, automation, reporting, pytest, jira-rest-api

Looking for a solution for collecting results from py.test automation framework to Jira, Adaptavist plug-in. Kanoah is providing documentation for **Adaptavist Test Management for JIRA REST API**. The documentation is not clear about how to Post results from the py.test or another test automation framework.

Example of :

```
[
    {
      "status": "Fail",
      "testCaseKey": "JQA-T1234",
      "environment": "Firefox",
      "comment": "The test has failed on some automation tool procedure.",
      "userKey": "vitor.pelizza",
      "executionTime": 180000,
      "executionDate": "2016-01-30T14:54:00Z",
      "issueLinks": ["JQA-123", "JQA-456"],
      "scriptResults": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "status": "Fail",
          "comment": "This step has failed."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "status": "Fail",
        "testCaseKey": "JQA-T5678"
    }
]
```

*The Question is:* *How to set up the the **py.test** framework?*

Pytest has the following options for reporting results of automation tests. But I'm sure how to setup of the options to send the results to Jira, Adaptavist.

**1. JUnit-Style Logs**

You can generate JUnit-style XML log files by running the following command:

> py.test --junitxml=result.xml

The XML file will be generated in the current directory.

**2. Generating a Plain Result**

> py.test --resultlog=result.log

**3. Sending a Test Report to Online pastebin Service**

The following command sends the entire execution log to an online remote pastebin
service:

> py.test -v --pastebin=all

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

JUnit could be used for sending results to Jenkins or Hudson

```
py.test --junitxml=[path to Jenkins]
```

There is also a Jenkins plugin Test Results Analyzer.
JUnit Plugin v.1.2-beta-4 is a dependency for Test Results Analyzer.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/test-results-analyzer

But this still does not answer the Question on 100% because the results should be captured by Adaptavist in Jira.